Vue: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations
I created an NPM package project: npm , Github
It is used to automatically upload to the server through SSH after the build is completed. I want to imitate the unplugin-auto-import package and use different suffixes to distinguish different frameworks. Now it can be compiled through tsup, but when I tried to introduce it in a newly created vite project, this error occurred. I confirm that the vite.js file exists after packaging. What else did I ignore?
package.json
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup"
  },
  ...
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs",
      "import": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "./dist/*",
        "./dist/index.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "inquirer": "^9.2.20",
    "node-ssh": "^13.2.0",
    "ora": "^8.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.2.11",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/inquirer": "^9.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.9",
    "@types/ssh2": "^1.15.0",
    "bumpp": "^9.4.1",
    "tsup": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}

tsup.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'tsup'

export default defineConfig({
    dts: true,
    clean: true,
    splitting: true,
    format: ['cjs', 'esm'],
    entry: ['src/*.ts']
})

vite project use: vite.config.ts
import AutoDeploy from 'vite-plugin-better-deploy/vite'

export default ({ mode }: { mode: any }) => {
    process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) }
    console.log(`[vite] run profile is ${mode}.`)
    return defineConfig({
        ...
        plugins: [
            AutoDeploy({
                host: '127.0.0.1',
                username: 'root',
                password: '123456',
                remotePath: '/www/wwwroot/test.com',
                previewPath: 'http://[::1]:8080',
                needInquire: false,
                removeLocal: true,
                removeRemote: true
            })
        ]
    })
}

npm run build output:
...
    vite.config.ts:9:23:
      9 │ import AutoDeploy from 'vite-plugin-better-deploy/vite'
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

failed to load config from C:\Users\qwq\Dev\HTML\vite_test\vite.config.ts
error during build:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.20.2/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1374:27: ERROR: [plugin: externalize-deps] Missing "./vite" specifier in "vite-plugin-better-deploy" package
...

